# How to detect in JSF when the backing bean method returns

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I need to detect when the backing bean method returns so that I can execute a javascript function. Alternatively, calling javascript code directly from within java source code would be helpful. Is there an example of how this is done?

Here, when this command button is clicked, both the action and onclick execute simultaneously. I need to execute the processAfterSave after the save method in the backing bean executes.

```
<h:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" type="submit" action="#{copyScript.save}" onclick="processAfterSave();" style="width: 75px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute the JS code in the result page. If the bean action returns to the same page, then you need to conditionally print the piece of JS code.

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{bean.saved}">
    <script>processAfterSave();</script>
</f:verbatim>
```

In combination with

```
private boolean saved;

public void save() {
    // Business logic here.
    // ...
    saved = true;
}

public boolean isSaved() {
    return saved;
}
```